# IE9 Beta and RC - Cannot select and then cut and paste text from a website

Tags: internet-explorer-9, cut-and-paste

This has been driving me nuts.  I was using the IE9 beta on Vista 64 bit and for the life of me I could not select text from a website to copy and paste.  Instead if the "I" I would get the grabby hand.  I just upgraded to the IE9 RC and still I have the grabby hand where I should be able to drag and select text.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Some pages do not allow highlight for copying, does it do it for all web pages?

Comment: It is every page that I want to cut and paste from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tools > Internet Options > Advanced Tab, do a Reset, close IE then re open it.

If this is too extreme, as it will disable all your add ons and clear history etc.

Go to Tools > Internet Options > Security Tab > Internet > Custom Level button > in the Miscellaneous category, be sure "Drag and drop or copy and paste files" is enabled.
[image]

Comment: My cut and paste setting was enabled.  Tried the reset and it worked perfectly!  You saved me from going crazy!  By the way how did you find out about this feature--I think it could come in handy.

Comment: Yes it is handy for solving IE problems, I forget where I learned about the reset button.